# Twilio Autopilot Conversation Flow?

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

I'm current doing a thesis about chatbot survey (Created through code and able to gather information through dialog on facebook/slack). Currently I'm having a problem about conversation flow in Twilio. 
To simplify the conversation:

- Chatbot: Hey do you mind answering a couple of question?
- Costumer: If yes proceed to ask question/ If no then thanks the costumer and stop the conversation. 

  I used the example survey bot on Twilio Autopilot but it doesn't really have a "if/else" scenario. If Twilio doesn't have it then is there any other chatbot suitable for this?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can do `if/else` using Autopilot with [Twilio Functions](https://www.twilio.com/console/functions/manage), our serverless environment tool.

This [Node.js quickstart](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/quickstart/node) has the first few steps you'd need to make a voice bot with Autopilot.

You could have one Autopilot task and then use a conditional in the Twilio Function the task redirects to to check what the user said. The Twilio Autopilot task could include this JSON:

```
{
    "actions": [
        {
            "redirect": {
                  "uri": "https://YOUR-TWILIO-FUNCTION-URL.twil.io/actions",
                  "method": "POST"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And then the Function may include

```js
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    let responseObject = {};
    let memory = JSON.parse(event.Memory);
    console.log(memory.twilio.collected_data);
    let userInput = memory.twilio.collected_data.your_collect_function_name.answers.your_question_name.answer;
    console.log(num); //collected data from memory
    if(userInput == "pie") {
        //do whatever
    }
    else if (userInput == "cake") {
        // do something else
    }
    else {
        //do something else
    }
};
```

Let me know if this helps at all!

Answer (score 1):

It's actually pretty simple to do.

As @lizziepika mentioned, you have to utilize functions.

First, let's say you want to collect data from a question like so:
TASKS Example

```js
        {
        "actions": [
            {
                "collect": {
                    "name": "contact",
                    "questions": [
                        {
                            "question": "Are you a human?",
                            "name": "contact_human",
                            "type": "Twilio.YES_NO"
                        }
                    ],
                    "on_complete": {
                        "redirect": {
                            "method": "POST",
                            "uri": "https://Your_Twilio_Function_Domain.twil.io/Function_Name"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

On complete, the Autopilot will redirect to a Twilio Function.

A great example of a Twilio function for autopilot can be found here.
https://github.com/twilio/autopilot-templates/blob/master/Functions/simple_response.js

I have tweaked it for our example.

```js
    exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
        //we get the Memory from the answered questions.
        let memory = JSON.parse(event.Memory);
        //set up an array of object "actions" for the autopilot to continue.
        let actions = [];
        let responseItem;

        //get the answer from Memory
        let human = Memory.twilio.collected_data.contact.answers.contact_human.answer; //Yes or No

        if(human === "Yes"){
            responseItem = {
                "say": "ANSWER YES - You are human"
            };

            actions.push(responseItem);


        }else{
            responseItem = {
                "say": "ANSWER No - You are NOT human"
            };

            actions.push(responseItem);
        }

        responseItem = {
            "redirect": {
                "method": "POST",
                "uri": "task://next_task"
            }
        };

        actions.push(responseItem);

        let respObj = {
            "actions": actions
        };
        callback(null, respObj);
    };
```

The beauty of this is that you can have the function respond with anything that would be present in a task. You can have the function respond with questions, actions, redirects, etc, as long as the payload is the same form as Autopilot Tasks.